# undefined method `reset_all` for nil

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
F
  An error occurred in an `around(:example)` hook
    NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_all' for nil:NilClass
    occurred at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rspec/mocks.rb:22:in `teardown'
```

I'm currently trying to run a ruby test suite, but running into issues when calling `rspec spec/`.  I'm getting the above traceback.  Any ideas as to what might cause this?  I've tried updating rspec to no avail.

Any debugging tips are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was simply a matter of an outdated ruby version!